# Visual Studio Undo One Letter

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In visual studio text editors the undo button only undoes one letter (keystroke) at a time.  I find myself just retyping things rather than hitting the undo button 50+ times to go back to 2seconds ago. I feel like undo should should undo a few words of text at a time. Is there a way to change settings to accomplish this or is it just an annoyance that we have to deal with?

Do you feel like this is frustrating as well? Cheers.

Comment: I feel like this used to be a setting, because I used to put it to "undo character by character" on purpose, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undo "undoes" your last ACTION.  If you highlight an entire word and hit delete then undo will bring back the entire word.  If you delete single characters then it will only bring back single characters.  Just hold the undo key combo down instead of hitting the keys repeatedly.

Comment: Just another way MS ruin things.

Answer (score 1):

You could hold down the undo button. Other than that, not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Undo/Redo Stack -- quite simple, and good when you need to back further:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/11/using-the-undo-and-redo-stack-vstipedit0045.aspx